# Scala - how to get and print the contents of Either?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm processing data where some records may be corrupted. So I decided to explore the data and used `Either` to divide valid and invalid records.

I figured out how to count the number of each kind of records and now getting the output for `failedCount` and `successCount` successfully.

But I have a problem with printing out each invalid (Left) sale record. What could be wrong with my approach?

I don't get any output when printing out `failedSales`

```
  def filterSales(rawSales: RDD[Sale]): RDD[(String, Sale)] = {

    val filteredSales = rawSales
      .map(sale => {
        val saleOption = Try(sale.id -> sale)
        saleOption match {
          case Success(successSale) => Right(successSale)
          case Failure(e) => Left(s"Corrupted sale: $sale;", e)
        }
      })
    val failedCount: Long = filteredSales.filter(_.isLeft).count()
    val successCount: Long = filteredSales.filter(_.isRight).count()
    println("FAILED SALES COUNT: " + failedCount)
    println("SUCCESS SALES COUNT: " + successCount)

    // Problem here
    val failedSales: RDD[Either.LeftProjection[(String, Throwable), (String, Sale)]] = filteredSales.map(_.left)
    println("FAILED SALES: ")
    // Doesn't produce any output 
    failedSales.foreach(println)
  }
```

Comment: what is `.map(_.left).filter(_.e.isLeft)` supposed to be good for? What's the advantage over calling `filter(_.isLeft)` directly?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin wow that's weird.. you are right )) will fix it

Comment: What have you done now, does it have anything to do with what I proposed in the comment?

Answer (score 1):

When you call `foreach(fn)` on an RDD then the funtion `fn` (`println` in your case) is executed on the slave nodes where the RDD is distributed. So it's happening *somewhere* but not on the driver program you're looking at.

If you have a small data set then you could `collect()` the RDD so the data is returned to your driver and you can `println` that.

If you have large data, you could `saveAsTextFile()` so it gets written to HDFS and you can download from there.

Comment: When I do `failedSales.collect().foreach(println)` I'm not getting any output

Comment: I guess that would only work if you are in local mode. In cluster mode your best bet would be with `saveAsTextFile()`.